# Are single-line comments allowed in multi-line PHP attribute declarations

Tags: php

This PHP code runs ok:

```php
<?php

#[Block(
  id: "system_main_block",
  // comment here!
  admin_label: "more text",
  forms: [
    'settings_tray' => FALSE,
  ],
)]
class Foo {}

#[\Attribute(\Attribute::TARGET_CLASS)]
class Block {}

print 'Ok!';
```

But I can't find anything in PHP docs that says single-line comments in attributes are allowed.

Is there anywhere it's documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are part of the [basic syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php) of the language. They're discarded (treated like whitespace) before parsing any other language elements.

So you should be able to use both single-line and multi-line comments in attribute declarations, just like anywhere else in the source code.